# Compare two columns of lists in pandas dataframe to get number of elements added and deleted as 2 additional separate columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with 2 columns of lists. I would like to have 2 additional columns with the number of elements added and deleted when comparing the column of "word2" with the column of "word1".

| word1 | word2 |
| --- | --- |
| [apple, orange] | [tomato, cucumber] |
| [banana, kiwi] | [kiwi, mango] |

My expected dataframe is as below. How can I accomplish this efficiently?

| word1 | word2 | added | deleted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [apple, orange] | [tomato, cucumber] | 2 | 2 |
| [banana, kiwi] | [kiwi, mango] | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way to do this is with [set difference operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) in Python and then apply that to each row.

In the example below, we get the difference between the two sets in the column. The difference between word2 and word1 tells you the rows that are added. The difference between word1 and word2 tells you what was deleted:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "word1": [["apple", "orange"], ["banana", "kiwi"]],
    "word2": [["tomato", "cucumber"], ["kiwi", "mango"]]
})

df["added"] = df.apply(lambda row: len(set(row.word2) - set(row.word1)), axis=1)
df["deleted"] = df.apply(lambda row: len(set(row.word1) - set(row.word2)), axis=1)

df
#>              word1               word2  added  deleted
#> 0  [apple, orange]  [tomato, cucumber]      2        2
#> 1   [banana, kiwi]       [kiwi, mango]      1        1
```

You may also consider [numpy set operations](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.set.html) if performance is a major concern.

Comment: I think the bottleneck here will be always the use of `DataFrame.apply`, and using `set` will be faster than using numpy set operations (unless each list is much much larger). Therefore I recommend using something like `code_str = "\ndef count_added_deleted(row):\n    w1, w2 = map(set, row[['word1', 'word2']])\n    row['added'] = len(w2 - w1)\n    row['deleted'] = len(w1 - w2)\n    return row\n\ndf.apply(count_added_deleted, axis=1)\n"` (run `print(code_str)` to get the correct format), to avoid using `apply`/ iterating over the rows twice.